# How to create a navigation bar in xaml, which can scale with different screen resolutions?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

```
<Grid
    Width="auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Width="auto" Background="Red"
        >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="Green"
                                ></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Blue" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" 
                        Margin="0,0,120,0" 
                        Width="auto"
                       >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Image>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is the code I am using to display the nav bar , where this is written in Controller, and the navbar images are populated dynamically using Binding.

I am trying to create a nav bar, which could be used on different screen resolutions, I have tried with various methods , but it is not scaling according to different screen resolutions

Comment: How do you want it to scale? It could either wrap based on the width available (and maintain the same individual nav bar item size), or the items on the nav bar shrink/grow to fill the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to remove `Grid.ColumnSpan="4"`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does answer it in a way. It solves a problem I see with the code that could prevent the control from scaling as seems to be its possible intent. If that doesn't answer the question - I'll get a comment and I will either remove the answer or add to it. Your comment isn't productive though and incites arguments. Obviously I realize how things work on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing interest in answering my question, I got the issue resolved using a Viewbox.I placed all the above code inside the viewbox and it worked perfectly.